# How Do I add this banner to my page with out making a blank line?

Tags: css, html, space

I need positioning help.
I have tried almost every thing and I still can't get rid of that blank space,does any one know how to fix this issue?I am new to html so I only know some of the basics.

```
<html>
<head>   
<title>Lost Legends Motor Cycle Club</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2C3539"text="white">
<div class="textContainer">
<center>
<h1 class="mainheading"><u><font color="#0033cc">Lost Legends MC</font></u></h1><div>           </div>

<a href="index.html" class="patch">Home</a>
<a href="roster.html" class="roster">Roster</a>
<a href="patches.html" class="patch2">Patches</a>
<a href="lock.html" class="member">Members</a>
<!-- Start Countdown -->
<span id="counts">
<div class="widget fullContainer" style="overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:5px">
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div style="font-family: Oswald; font-size: 22px">
        <div class="featureBox" style="height: 100px; background:           url(http://media.gtanet.com/gta-5/images/gtav-release-date.png) no-repeat;">
            <!-- counter -->
            <div id="counterbox"></div>
            <script src="http://media.gtanet.com/gta-5/javascript/counter-previews.js"        type="text/javascript"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">initcounter();</script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="topLeft"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="topRight"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="bottomLeft"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="bottomRight"></div>
</div>
<!-- End Countdown -->
</span>
<hr>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
div.textContainer { width: 1340;}
#counts {

top:90px;
left:0px;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

CSS

```
hr {background-color:blue;height: 5px;border-style:none;}
.patch {
position:relative;
margin-left: 600px;
margin-top: -50px;

-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
background-color:#213a9e;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
text-indent:0px;
border:1px solid #000000;
display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
width:116px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}.patch:hover {
background-color:#364d63;
}.patch:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;}

.patch2 {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee4f9;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee4f9;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee4f9;
background-color:#213a9e;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
text-indent:0px;
border:1px solid #000000;
display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
width:116px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}.patch2:hover {
background-color:#364d63;
}.patch2:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
.member {
position:relative;



-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
background-color:#213a9e;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
text-indent:0px;
border:1px solid #000000;
display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
width:116px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}.member:hover {
background-color:#364d63;
}.member:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;}
.roster {

-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee4f9;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee4f9;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee4f9;
background-color:#213a9e;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
text-indent:0px;
border:1px solid #000000;
display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
width:116px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}.roster:hover {
background-color:#364d63;
}.roster:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbwTr.png
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What blank space? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want the banner to be on the same line as the buttons

Comment: What do you mean all of it?

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your answer to cut away unnecessary parts of the code, and maybe put the CSS in a separate code box? If you could specify your question a bit more rather than just saying "blank space", that would also make it easier to help you. A screenshot wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

Mate this is a bit basic and I have just taken a piece of your page.

What you need to do is get the buttons to float right, so that the banner can fit in. At the moment you have:

```
margin-left: 600px
```

on your first button, and that means that even though you cannot see anything to the left of it, and though it appears as if the banner can fit in there, that space belongs to that button and the banner cannot go in there. As such it is pushed to the bottom and you see the space.

So have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mQUQK/

I have created an extra container div around the buttons and floated that div to the right.